# how to sort 2 different columns in google sheet individually?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that has 2 columns with integer rows in it. Both these columns have no relation to each other. But when I apply a A->Z sort on the 1st column the 2nd column values also change and vice versa. My task is to SORT these 2 columns individually in ascending order and create a 3rd column which checks if the values of this 1st 2 column are equal or not.

```
Example:
Col1   Col2
4        5
1        8
2        9 
5        1

Expected Output after sorting them individually:
col1   col2
1        1
2        5
4        8
5        9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Solution 1:**

You can filter and sort  each column separately:

[image: idea]

---

### **Solution 2:**

Another solution would be to create the desired output by sorting each column separately and concatenating the results:

`={{"Col1";sort(A2:A)},{"Col2";sort(B2:B)}}`

[image: result]